# Выполнение действия сразу после запуска приложения

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, qthread, qtimer

Пользуюсь *PyQt5*. Приложение работает так, что при запуске требуется время 
на *обновление некоторых данных, около 5 секунд*.

Если выполнять обновление внутри инициализации класса приложения, то соответственно окно не запускается, пока не завершится обновление.

Как можно сделать, чтобы:

- вначале окно полностью запустилось,
- а затем сразу же выполнялись определенные действия ?

Пока обновление выполняется будут задизейблены все кнопки и выведено  информационное сообщение, с этим проблем нет.

Comment: Splash screen with waiting cursor / progress bar?

Comment: не хотелось бы делать еще одно окно, есть еще варианты?

Comment: А как пользователь узнает, что надо ждать, а не выкидывать ваше приложение сразу в мусорник?

Comment: Создать поток и пока он работает дизейблить все что надо

Comment: @0andriy в окне приложения есть статусбар, там будет информация, плюс кнопки отключены

Comment: @AlexanderChernin поток создать прямо внутри __init__?

Comment: да, почему нет? Окно покажется, а кнопки будут залочены, пока не отработает поток. Хотя, вариант со сплеш-окном тоже хороший

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое, что надо понимать - это то, что тяжелые задачи выполняются в `дочернем потоке`.

Второе, чтобы показать окно, а затем выполнить какие-то действия, вам поможет `Таймер однократного срабатывания`, срабатывает только один раз.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QProgressBar, QPushButton,\
    QMainWindow, QLabel


class Worker(QThread):
    valueChanged = pyqtSignal(int)                     #  сигнал изменения значения

    def run(self):
        for i in range(1, 101):
            self.valueChanged.emit(i)
            QThread.msleep(100)


class Window(QMainWindow):                      
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Window, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.statusBar().showMessage("Через 3 сек. запускается обновление ! ")
        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        self.label = QLabel('Какая-то Label')
        self.button = QPushButton('Какая-то кнопка')
        self.button.setEnabled(False)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(centralWidget)        
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

        self.progressBar = QProgressBar()
        self.progressBar.setRange(0, 100)

        #  дочерний поток
        self._thread = Worker(self)
        self._thread.finished.connect(self.threadFinished)
        self._thread.valueChanged.connect(self.progressBar.setValue)

        # Таймер однократного срабатывания срабатывает только один раз
        QTimer.singleShot(3000, self.onStart)                           # <-----

    def onStart(self):
        self.statusBar().showMessage("Выполняется  обновление -> ")
        self.statusBar().reformat()
        self.statusBar().addPermanentWidget(self.progressBar)
        self._thread.start()                     # начать дочерний поток

    def threadFinished(self):
        self.statusBar().showMessage("Обновление выполнено! ")
        self._thread.deleteLater
        self.button.setEnabled(True)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        if self._thread.isRunning():
            self._thread.quit()
        del self._thread
        super(Window, self).closeEvent(event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.resize(450, 200)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: очень круто, благодарю!